# Is the current situation possible for recreaction in a lab?

Tags: pressure, temperature

I want to convert cellulose to another form (crystalline => amorphous).
Cellulose requires a temperature of 320 °C and pressure of 25 MPa to become amorphous in water.(Is the pressure achievable in the lab?)

Is this doable in the lab and how should I begin on reproducing that situation (which tools would I need) ?

I'm guessing that a bunsen burner would produce high enough temperatures (but I'm not quite sure about the pressure)

EDIT (info) : I know that this is a chemical process, but aren't you physicists better in figuring out the 'realisticativity' of pressures?

Comment: I think this is probably better suited to [chemistry.se]

Comment: but pressure? I know that this is a chemical process, but aren't you physicists better in figuring out the 'realisticativity' of pressures?

Comment: That pressure is probably within the reach of most standard chemistry labs, I think. The [Haber process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haber%E2%80%93Bosch_process#The_process) runs at or slightly below 25 MPa. I would ask a chemist: the mainly theoretical physicist crowd here is indeed good at figuring out the 'in-principle-realisticality' of processes, but whether _you_ can do it depends on the lab you actually have available.